# How to install R packages when github is blocked using papaja as an example

Tags: r, github, papaja, remotes

I thought I would post this as an answer to anyone having problems installing papaja (or other packages) when behind a firewall that doesn't allow github

**The problem**

For reasons I dont fully understand, the only way I am able to use github R packages is to download them into my github desktop and then use them using the `remotes::install_local("C:\\[path]\\GitHub\\papaja")` function. This has worked for all the R packages available from github (CRAN installations are fine).

However this is not the case with `papaja` which gives me the error:

```
'Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = h) : 
  Failed to connect to api.github.com port 443: Connection refused'
```

I suspect this is because a call is being made to github during the package installation (otherwise why dont I get this issue with all of the other packages I've installed this way).

Answer (score 1):

**The attempts**

So I went ahead and tried

```
remotes::install_local("C:\\[path]\\GitHub\\papaja",dependencies=FALSE)
```

It gave me the error:

```
ERROR: dependencies 'bookdown', 'rmdfiltr' are not available for package 'papaja'
```

**The answer**

So I installed these separately from CRAN and then re ran

```
remotes::install_local("C:\\[path]\\GitHub\\papaja",dependencies=FALSE)
```

and the papaja successfully installed. So I guess the installation for the dependencies `bookdown` and `rmdfiltr` are making a call to github when they could be installed from CRAN?

So I guess if you get the same error, switch off dependecy installation and install them separately